# Pick up slowed after service in bike

Tags: motorcycle, suzuki, service

After recent service of my bike Suzuki GSXR, its acceleration reduced the difference I can feel every-time. It has 30000 km only & it was regularly serviced with no major changes to machine.

How can I fix this? or Do I need to go to service center again & issue complaint for this issue after servicing?

Comment: which gsxr is it? What year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check for a pinched fuel line below the tank, be ready to replace the power control module. i've seen many gsxr burn out the pcm when tuning or wrenching. i have yet to understand why they crap out so easily. (people stop because this is a observation not from my tinkering with the unknown.) good luck bro.

Comment: Fuel line is intact, but definitely some issue with tuning, seems I need to visit service center on weekend which takes time so I was trying to explore issue if it is something that I can fix.